# How to exclude matched group after a non-matched group - regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I wrote a regex which matches a string using regex groups pattern:

`^(?<serialCode>[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3})(?<serialMarket>[a-zA-Z]{0,2})(?<serialSuffix>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$`

Basically it says:

- 1st group should be 3 characters long and contain only alphanumeric characters
- 2nd group should be 2 characters long and contain only letters
- last group can be any length and contain alphanumeric characters

This translates to:

Match 1

Full match  0-8 `abcfobar`

Group `serialCode`  0-3 abc

Group `serialMarket`    3-5 fo

Group `serialSuffix`    5-8 bar

[image]

*The above case is expected result.*

When the regex fails as it should for a string like: `abc33bar`, it fails because 4th an 5th characters are digits instead of letters, this is correct. The issue is that the characters which should match the second group move to the next matching group(serialSuffix), and it results in:

Match 1

Full match  0-8 abc33bar

Group `serialCode`  0-3 abc

Group `serialMarket`    3-3

Group `serialSuffix`    3-8 33bar

[image]

How do I prevent creation of non-matching and matching groups after the non-matched group(including non-matched group)?

Comment: Why do you allow 0-length groups if you want to forbid non-matching groups? Can't you just use `{3}` and `{2}` instead of `{0,3}` and `{0,2}`, respectively?

Comment: Well, I want to be able to do the matching for every character in the group while let's say typing in an HTML input field. If I use `{3}` instead fo `{0,3}` then the match won't take place if I have only "abc" for example. If I have only "abc" as a string and I apply the regex, than I still need to validate that first group.

Comment: When I have `abc33bar` it should return only the first group(eg: serialCode: `abc`). If the second group does not match, even though the 3rd does, then still only the first matching group should be returned.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?<serialCode>[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})(?:(?<serialMarket>[a-zA-Z]{2})(?<serialSuffix>[a-zA-Z0-9]*))?` https://regex101.com/r/QvTIkO/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, almost, in the example provided by you there's also a match on the second group now when the first character is a letter and the second is a number, it should be a match only when both characters from that group are letters.

Comment: I get these matches with only a first group https://regex101.com/r/i3M69V/1

Comment: It should match the 2nd group and the 3rd group only when the length of the group is respected, modified yours a bit but still doesn't do what it shoud because it creates the 3rd group when clearly the 2nd one should not be matched because the second character from it is a number https://regex101.com/r/i3M69V/3

Comment: @anubhava, then it won't match the first character in second group.

Comment: Like in `{1,2}` then? `^(?<serialCode>[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})(?:(?<serialMarket>[a-zA-Z]{1,2})(?<serialSuffix>[a-zA-Z0-9]*))?` https://regex101.com/r/Pc3FxX/1 But you commented `it should be a match only when both characters from that group are letters.` and that should be 2 characters in group 2 right?

Comment: No. When the second group is partially matched then the 3rd group should not be created/matched. But the 2nd group should still be created with the matched character.

Comment: I am not sure you can reuse the double naming of the capture groups in Javascript, but either match a 2 a-z followed by capturing the rest or single a-z `^(?<serialCode>[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z]{2}(.*)|[a-zA-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/d83lda/1

Comment: That is almost close but it seems one step ahead the matching.

Comment: @IonutNecula Can you explain what you mean by that? Or update the regex101 link with what the matches should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex with a lookbehind in last optional capture group:

```sh
^(?<serialCode>[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})(?:(?<serialMarket>[a-zA-Z]{1,2})(?<serialSuffix>(?<=^.{5})[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI0708/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?<serialCode>[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})`: Match and capture 3 alphanumerics in `serialCode` capture group
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?<serialMarket>[a-zA-Z]{1,2})`: Match and capture 1 or 2 letters in `serialMarket` capture group
  - `(?<serialSuffix>(?<=^.{5})[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?`: Match and capture 0 or more alphanumerics in *optional* `serialSuffix` capture group. This group will capture only after first 5 characters using lookbehind assertion `(?<=^.{5})`
- `)?`: End non-capture group (optional)

Comment: Hello. Is there any way to do the same thing as above, but this time avoiding lookbehind, because it seems that is not supported by Safari: https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind ?  It throws an error: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`

Comment: You may [use this regex](https://regex101.com/r/FCChB5/1)

Comment: This is a bit different than the previous working regex. The first 3 characters are not matched one by  one. Is there a way to have that too?

Comment: It is different because there is no lookbehind support. But if you compare both demo links, content of the captured groups are same.

Comment: Is it possible to make those first 3 characters to be matched one by one instead of when reaching to the 3rd character only? if you look at the previous demo and add just one letter on a line, you can see that it's being matched. In the new regex that doesn't happen.

Comment: Just check content of capture group `serialMarket` which remains same in both regex

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jNEnr0/1 This is the one which is correct. Observe the last inputted line is being matched when even a single character is inputted. And this is the new one https://regex101.com/r/bC0zas/1 where the last line with single character is not partially matched.

Comment: But I had `[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}` in my regex whereas you are showing `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3}`. Try this `^(?=[a-z0-9]{3}[a-z]{2}(?<serialSuffix>[a-z0-9]+)|.*)(?<serialCode>[a-z0-9]{1,3})(?:(?<serialMarket>[a-z]{1,2}))?`

Comment: `^(?=[a-z0-9]{3}[a-z]{2}(?<serialSuffix>[a-z0-9]+)|.*)(?<serialCode>[a-z0-9]{1,3})(?:(?<serialMarket>[a-z]{1,2}))?` This fixes the matching for the first 3 characters, but the last group is not matched at all in the "Full match"

Comment: I have suggested already to look at contents of 3 capture groups not the full match since we are using a *work around* here